# Flutter google_maps_flutter into existing project

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, flutter

I am trying to integrate [google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_maps_flutter) into an existing project.

The maps component works only when running directly the "my_flutter" project on the device (the same code).

When I try to run the flutter module from an existing app, the maps component is empty and no logs are available (or usable).

(Flutter doctor does not output any errors).

I've followed the steps for both the **my_flutter/.iOS** and **my_flutter/.android** projects and I also followed them for the projects that integrate **my_flutter**.

**[Source](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_maps_flutter)**:

> **Android**
>     Specify your API key in the application manifest
>   android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest ...
  <application ...
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
               android:value="YOUR KEY HERE"/>
```

> **iOS** 
>    Specify your API key in the application delegate ios/Runner/AppDelegate.m:

```
include "AppDelegate.h"
include "GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h"        
import "GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h" 

@implementation AppDelegate

    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application   didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions { 
           [GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"YOUR KEY HERE"];   
           [GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:self];   
           return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];  
     }   
@End
```

> Opt-in to the embedded views preview by adding a boolean property to
>   the app's Info.plist file with the key
>   io.flutter.embedded_views_preview and the value YES.

---

I suspect that I what I am trying is not possible yet with the current version on the library and it may come as a new feature when the library is not in "developer preview".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found that I had to:

```
GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: flutterViewController.pluginRegistry());
```

Comment: Where did you do this at? Main.dart?

Comment: In the app delegate of the iOS project that imported the flutter module. (the main iOS project, not the one create by flutter)

Answer (score 0):

Did you set a latitude and longitude in the Google Maps param?

If you're setting your API key and doing what it said, it should work fine

Comment: Yes. The maps component works only when running directly the "my_flutter" project on the device (same code).